# SQL Simplify View, Merge Columns into One Column, Matrix, Union

Tags: sql, sql-server, matrix, merge

Apologies for the vague title, I don't really know where to start to explain what I'm trying to achieve!

I have a view that is identifying football betting odds based on Home Win, Away Win, or a draw. The different types of selection currently have their own column, but I need to create a new column that has the bet selection (home, draw, win), with another new column that will show the odds for that selection. The image below best explains what I am trying to achieve

[image]

Any idea on how this achieved?!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNION :

```
SELECT t.event_id,'home' as selection,home_odds as odds FROM YourTable t
UNION ALL
SELECT t.event_id,'away',away_odds FROM YourTable t
UNION ALL
SELECT t.event_id,'draw',draw_odds FROM YourTable t
```

Comment: It worked up to Away, i.e. - it provided the column for Away and Draw, but when I tried to work up to the next level, Draw is no longer appearing at all, but only shows Home and Away

Comment: @GlennCooper That doesn't make any sense, it should work unless you provide the wrong column names

Comment: It works, stupid me had the number of results restricted to 1,000 and they were hiding at the bottom :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Select only the draw part, and tell me what is the output

Comment: No problem :) @GlennCooper